# lazy attribute in the IoT Agent of FIWARE

Tags: iot, fiware

I'm trying to set the **IoT Agent UL** of FIWARE in the "**lazy**" configuration.
I cannot find info/example/doc on the net.
Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, the lazy attribute feature will be implemented in the next 9 months as you can check in the roadmap (https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/docs/roadmap.md#medium-term)

Comment: But it will interesting to know what type of IoT Agent support all config (active, lazy and command) for both ngsi versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of a lazily provisioned device within the [Unit Tests](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/test/unit/lazyAndCommands/lazy-devices-test.js) of the IoT Node Agent library.

Provisioning lazy attributes is merely a matter of setting an attribute in the `lazy` array, rather than the `attributes` array.

```js
'Motion': {
     commands: [],
     lazy: [
              {
                 name: 'moving',
                 type: 'Boolean'
              }
           ],
     staticAttributes: [
              {
                  'name': 'location',
                  'type': 'Vector',
                  'value': '(123,523)'
              }
           ],
     active: []
}
```

The difference is under the hood - a **registration** is automatically set up so that any request on the context broker is passed to the IoT Agent in the form of a batch request.

Under NGSI-v2, for lazy attributes this means that the IoT Agent receives a **POST** on the `/v2/op/query` endpoint, and the `setDataQueryHandler()` handler is called. Further documentation can found [here](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usermanual/index.html#iotagentlibsetdataqueryhandler)

How (and indeed if) this endpoint is supported is a matter for each individual IoT Agent, but assuming you are writing your own custom agent, it could make contact with the device, request the required information and respond back in the `callback()` as shown:

```js
callback(null, {
    type: 'TheType',
    isPattern: false,
    id: 'EntityID',
    attributes: [
        {
            name: 'lumniscence',
            type: 'Integer',
            value: '432'
        }
    ]
});
```

This would enable queries on the Context Broker to be delegated down to the devices themselves, which may be useful in some case, but of course requires that the devices are intelligent and powerful enough to be able to respond to queries in a timely manner. In many low-power devices this is not the case, and therefore lazy attributes are not supported.

Comment: Thank you Jason. Under NGSIv2, is the IoTAgent or Orion receives a POST on the /v2/op/query?

Comment: Under NGSIv2, Orion receives either a single GET request or a /v2/op/query batch request from an outside application (e.g. curl request). Then, assuming a registration has been set up, it forwards the request to the IoT Agent as  a /v2/op/query batch request

Comment: Under NGSI-LD, Orion-LD receives a GET request and  forwards the same GET request to the registered IoT Agent.